# The collection of maps to a (commutative) monoid is a (commutative) monoid, via Eckmann-Hilton

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories, additive-categories

A commutative monoid $M$ has the nice property that given a set $S$, the set of functions $S \to M$ forms a commutative monoid (under pointwise addition). The same statement without any mention of commutativity is true.

Now, consider a cartesian closed category $C$. In other words, the category $C$ has finite products, is considered as a monoidal category under $\times$, and has internal mapping objects. Fix an object $S \in C$. I believe it is true that **if $M$ is a commutative monoid in $C$, then $M^S$ is a commutative monoid in $C$.**

> Is there a slick proof of this fact using the Eckmann-Hilton argument?

I actually have not seen a proof of this fact by any means. I think it's just an exercise in handling exponential objects. I would guess that the candidate multiplication $M^S \times M^S \to M^S$ is the map corresponding to $f \mapsto (S \xrightarrow{f \times g} M \times M \to M)$ under the identification $\text{Hom}(M^S \times M^S, M^S) \cong \text{Hom}(M^S, (M^S)^{M^S})$ granted by closedness.

My question is whether you can alternatively just show that this operation and another commute over each other (in the sense of the Eckmann-Hilton argument) thus are equal and commutative. One idea is to generalize the following example.

> **Example.** Given a set $S$ and a commutative monoid $M$. Then we can define two monoidal operations on $\text{Hom}(S,M)$ which take $f,g$ to two maps:
> $$
> X \xrightarrow{\Delta} X \times X \to X \coprod X \xrightarrow{f \coprod g} M
> $$
> $$
> X \xrightarrow{f \times g} M \times M \to M
> $$
> Which (either by directly checking or by the Eckmann-Hilton argument) are equal and commutative operations.

One of the maps in this example is defined using finite coproducts. *If* we assume $C$ has finite coproducts, then I think one can argue identically (via Eckmann-Hilton) that $M^S$ is a commutative monoid object. **That is to say, if we add the assumption that $C$ has finite coproducts, then the answer to my question is yes.**

I am curious if there's a way to make an Eckmann-Hilton type proof without using coproducts.

Comment: I never thought of the Eckmann-Hilton argument as being relevant to this sort of fact. Isn't it the case that, in any cartesian-closed category, if an object $M$ with some morphisms $M^n$ satisfies an equational identity, then so does $M^S$ for any $S$ (equipped with the operations coming from those of $M$ via $(M^S)^n\cong(M^n)^S$. That covers thd case of (commutative) monoids provided that you consider them as having not just the multiplication $M^2\to M$ but also the unit element $M^0=1\to M$.

Comment: In my previous comment, I should have specified that the exponent $n$ is a natural number, not an object of the category; $M^n$ means $M\times M\times\dots\times M$ with $n$ factors.